# How to properly localize Google Map?

Tags: google-maps

How to localize Google Map on [my site](http://yonash.rakhiv-tour.com/how-to-get-there-en.html)?

Comment: You mean like the first hit on googling for "google maps localization"?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an hl parameter to your JavaScript line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=abcdefg&hl=de" />
```

For the supported language parameters look [here](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for my include of: maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=de&hl=de

Comment: Make sure you include the version parameter in the querystring (i.e. `&v=2`). I think languages were only supported from version 2 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

If your language is one that Google support, then you just need to specify the hl parameter when you load the API **and** use the locale setting when you use GDirections

```
  gdir.load("from: Detroit to: Dayton", {locale:"fr"});.
```

If your language is not one that Google supports, then you need to perform lots of GAddMessages() calls, which is how the Google Maps API loader does it. But that leaves three types of text that either don't use that mechanism, or use the values set by the loader before we get control. These are the map types, the copyright texts, and GDirections.

- To localize the map types texts, you
  need to create your own custom map
  types that are clones of the Google
  map types but with changed "name",
  "shortName", "errorMessage" and "alt"
  parameters.
- To localize the copyright texts you
  can write your own
  custommap.getCopyrights() method
  which reads through the prefixes and
  replaces any occurrences of "Map
  Data" and "Imagery" with the
  equivalent in the desired language.
- There's no reasonable way to produce
  GDirections details in unsupported
  languages.